# Windows 10 HID mouse device driver corrupted or missing

Tags: drivers, windows-10, mouse

Suddenly after a power failure which caused my PC to shutdown abruptly, I noticed that the mouse pointer was missing after I started the PC. When I went to see the device status, the device was showing a yellow triangle and the following message was displaying in the device status.

```
Windows cannot load the device driver for this hardware. The driver may be corrupted or missing. (Code 39)

{Unable to Load Device Driver}
%hs device driver could not be loaded.
Error Status was 0x%x
```

I have tried update driver, but that is not working. It's become very difficult to operate my computer. Please help.

Comment: You can use the `tab` key as well as arrow keys.... (lol)

Comment: http://www.eightforums.com/drivers-hardware/48907-keyboard-mouse-cd-rom-drive-stopped-responding.html this might give u some solutions

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of things you can try (of course you will need another mouse or use MouseKeys to perform some actions):

1. Enable <kbd>F8</kbd> during boot by opening a console as an administrator and typing:

   ```
   bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy
   ```
2. Press the <kbd>F8</kbd> key during boot and then choose the option *Last Known Good Configuration (advanced)*.

   [image]
3. Go to safe mode and see if your driver is correctly recognized. If it's recognized then most likely a program you were running has caused the damage.
4. Uninstall your mouse driver, then unplug it from the computer and then reconnect it again. Be careful when choosing a checkbox during the driver uninstall that allows you to **completely** remove the driver.
5. Use a program like [SamDrivers](http://getintopc.com/softwares/drivers-softwares/samdrivers-16-1-iso-jan-2016-free-download/) (freeware) and install your drivers using the program SDI Drivers included in SamDrivers. Your system can tell you that your drivers are completely up-to-date, but that's not always true.

   [image]

I suggest keeping the <kbd>F8</kbd> key enabled during boot, but if you want to disable it, simply open a console as an administrator and type:

```
bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy standard
```

Comment: Awesome. Will try it out and let you know.

Comment: Jesus, alas `Last known Goof Configuration` didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried the remaining options? Going into Safe Mode could help.

Answer (score 1):

Use System Restore to restore your system (and the driver) back to a working state.

Comment: I don't keep `System Restore` enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the power failure caused some damage to Windows,
which you need to repair.

- Check the state of the hard drive and correct any errors [using chkdsk](https://windowsinstructed.com/run-chkdsk-windows/)
- Check Windows integrity by [sfc /scannow](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-sfc-command-run-windows-10-a.html)
- [Use DISM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824869.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) : `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`
- As a last resort, do [Repair Install Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Ensure you have good backups before starting.

Comment: Note : Enabling System Restore in the future is a good idea.

Comment: I had to reinstall Windows 10 from scratch. But will keep this mind from next time.

Answer (score -2):

1. Go to your Windows Search, type in "drivers" and "update device drivers" should come up.
2. Click on it then go to "Mice and other pointing devices".
3. Click into it then go to your mouse (will pop up if plugged in), right click on it then "Update driver software".
4. Choose "Search automatically" and it should download the newest drivers for you.

Comment: If your mouse driver is faulty, how do you click? ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek use another mouse?

Comment: Its a standard mouse driver no? (You *could* use keyboard + arrows and hit enter).

Comment: I've enabled mouse keys and tried to update the device driver, but it says that the latest driver is already installed and then back to square one, mouse is not detected.